# Implementing Show/Hide of dialog fields on selection from dropdown in CQ5

Tags: javascript, aem

I have an implementation where I have to select from a drop-down (Image or video). On the basis of this selection, Image path field and Alt Text should be displayed in dialog on the selection of Image (other fields should remain hidden)and Video ID and Alt Text should be displayed on selection of Video (other fields should remain hidden)from the drop-down. This entire thing has to be implemented in multi-field. Each multi-field will have drop-down along with fields.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please put on some code using **Snippet** for SO users to understand better.

Answer (score 1):

On the component create a clientlib - 
[example](http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/clientlibs-explained-example/)

/yourcomponent/clientlib/authoring.js

On authoring.js create the javascript code to handle the hide/show functionality for your fields

```
Yourcompany.authoring = {

    hideFields: function(this, value, sChecked){
        //your code goes here        
    }
}
```

[Using cq5's extJs API](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/components/widgets.html)

In your AEM instance download the package called **Using ExtJS Widgets** (v01) from Package Share and install

On the drop-down node add a listeners node of type nt:unstructured and add a property **selectionchanged** with the following value:

```
function(this, value, sChecked ) { 
    Yourcompany.authoring.hideFieds(field, value, isChecked);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope the below serves your requirement:

http://adobeaemclub.com/toggle-fields-based-on-selection-in-granite-ui-dialogs/